# Содержимое консоли Javascript

Tags: javascript

Задача - с помощью javascript получить содержимое консоли в браузере. Каким методом и возможно ли вообще так сделать?

Comment: Это невозможно.

Answer (score 2):

Напрямую не возможно. Но вы можете переопределить console.log и всё, что должно попасть в консоль, приходит в вашу функцию и вы его можете использовать для решения своих задач:

```
var store = [];
var oldf = console.log;
console.log = function(){
   store.push(arguments);
   oldf.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript). Там же есть комментарии.

Comment: `console.table` поинтереснее будет...